# SOCKS4-5 network device driver

Tags: linux, proxy, socks, iproute2

There are methods of forcing programs to use SOCKS4-5 proxy's, such as socksify, tsocks and other LD_PRELOAD hijacking methods.

Is there a way of having a SOCKS proxy network device, such as one that shows up under ifconfig?

It would be nice to do policy routing against a SOCKS proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any such implementation. It's my feeling that it wouldn't really make much sense to try to embed SOCKS functionality at the level of the network device ([OSI-RM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) layer 2, the link layer), since the SOCKS protocol requires the services of the network layer (layer 4). But I am always open to a good counter argument!

Comment: There are other pseudo drivers available for other services that could be run alternatively from userland!

Comment: oh, we have khttpd too!